# What causes this Member AutoSync failure?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this table:

```
create table dbo.NotificationsIn
(
    NotificationID varchar(18) primary key,
    ArrivalTime datetime not null default getdate()
)
```

I insert to it like this:

```
public void InsertNotification(NotificationsIn notification)
{
    db.NotificationsIns.InsertOnSubmit(notification);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

where db is a LINQ DataContext.

I get the following exception after I insert a new record:

System.InvalidOperationException: Member AutoSync failure. For members to be Auto-Synced after insert, the type must either have an auto-generated identity, or a key that is not modified by the database after insert.

In the dbml, I have set the ArrivalTime property AutoGenerated = True and Auto-Sync = OnInsert. I have also tried Auto-Sync = Never, but the result is the same.

Any idea why I am getting this exception?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided your database layer information.
The simplest solution is to make the NotificationID column an Identity one. This should help.

Comment: The database is sql server 2k8. I can't make the NotificationID an Identity because it's value matters; it is supplied by an external system.

Comment: Then the better solution is to call the Refresh method. The AutoSync property is intended to be used with autogenerated properties, Refresh does not have this limitation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx

Comment: But the Auto-Sync property of NotificationID is already set to Never. ArrivalTime is set to Auto-Sync OnInsert, but it is autogenerated.